# VBA matching function

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am new to VBA and I am trying to create a function that matches an array of strings to a target string. I want it to return true if any of the strings in the array is contained within the target string.

I feel like this is a pretty simple function however I am having quite a lot of trouble with the syntax. Any advice would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function matching(ByRef stringList() As Variant, targetString As String)

    Dim index As Integer

    For index = 0 To UBound(stringList)
        If targetString Like "*" & stringList(index) & "*" Then
            matching = True
            Exit For
        Else
            matching = False
        End If
    Next index

End Function
```

**Use:**

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim stringList() As Variant

    stringList = Array("hi", "de", "ho")

    Debug.Print matching(stringList, "this")
    Debug.Print matching(stringList, "that")
    Debug.Print matching(stringList, "hollow")

End Sub
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
True
```

**Explanation:**

The asterisk when used with the Like operator acts as a wildcard as the OP stated he was interested in whether or not any of the strings were **contained** in the target string.